# How to make associate a file type with an Windows Phone application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

**I'm trying to make associate a file type with an Windows Phone application , so what its the right code to do this ?**

Comment: Stackoverflow is a site that is used to help resolve problems and errors. Please try researching examples and try them out. If you run into prolems, come back with the error.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you searched msdn? Please review [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that, but only on Windows Phone 8.

[Auto-launching apps using file and URI associations for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Fileassociations)

As stated there, it's done by manifest file:

```
<Extensions>
   <FileTypeAssociation Name="Windows Phone SDK test file type" TaskID="_default" NavUriFragment="fileToken=%s">
       <Logos>
           <Logo Size="small" IsRelative="true">Assets/sdk-small-33x33.png</Logo>
           <Logo Size="medium" IsRelative="true">Assets/sdk-medium-69x69.png</Logo>
           <Logo Size="large" IsRelative="true">Assets/sdk-large-176x176.png</Logo>
       </Logos>
       <SupportedFileTypes>
         <FileType ContentType="application/sdk">.sdkTest1</FileType>
         <FileType ContentType="application/sdk">.sdkTest2</FileType>

       </SupportedFileTypes>
   </FileTypeAssociation>
</Extensions>
```